# Determine if we can put '+' and '-' between numbers so that the result is divisible by a number: where's my mistake?

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

We have `howmanynums` numbers. We must determine if there's a way to put `'+'` and `'-'` between them in a way that makes the result divisible by given number `mod`.

(It is preferred to do it by means of dynamic programming, but I am just counting every sequence from the scratch because very short on time and just need it to work).

```c
int howmanynums, mod;

int ring(int num) {
    if ((num >= 0) && (num <= mod - 1))
        return num;
    if (num >= mod) {
        while (num >= mod)
            num -= mod;
        return num;
    }
    if (num < 0) {
        while (num < 0)
            num += mod;
        return num;
    }
}

long int p(int n) {
    long int t = 1;

    while (n > 0) {
        t *= 2; 
        n--;
    }
    return t;
}

int sequence[10000][2];

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    scanf("%d%d%d", &howmanynums, &mod, &sequence[0][0]);
    sequence[0][0] = ring(sequence[0][0]);
    int temp;
    int k = 1;
    while (k < howmanynums) {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        sequence[k][0] = ring(temp);
        sequence[k][1] = ring(-temp);
        k++;
    }

    long int x = (p(howmanynums - 1)); 
    while (x > 0) {
        long int a = sequence[0][0];
        long int permutation = x;
        long int insidePermutation = x % 2;
        int l = 1;
        while (l < howmanynums) { 
            a += sequence[l][insidePermutation]; 
            l++; 
            permutation = permutation / 2; 
            insidePermutation = permutation % 2; 
        }
        if (a % mod == 0) {
            printf("%s", "Divisible");
            goto e;
        }
        x--;
    }
     printf("%s", "Not divisible");

 e:
    return 0;
}
```

It passes 10 tests out of 20. I don't know the tests.

I also tried substituting all ints for long ints, but same result.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: What is your input? You need to find a case where your algorithm doesn't work and debug it. Test limits as given by the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your code and it looks OK to me. It should do the job. My only concern is efficiency. It takes about 20 seconds to find the answer "Not divisible" for the next sequence of 30 numbers: 30 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. Every additional number will double the previous time. So, the tests that your code didn't pass could be because of the allowed test time.

Dynamic programming is a must to pass the tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int howmanynums, mod, sequence[64];

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    // freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    scanf("%d%d", &howmanynums, &mod);
    if (howmanynums > 64)
    {
        printf("Too many %d", howmanynums);
    }
    int k = 0;
    while (k < howmanynums)
        scanf("%d", &sequence[k++]);
    int x = (2 << (howmanynums - 2)) - 1;
    bool divisible = false;
    while (!divisible && x >= 0)
    {
        int a = sequence[0], bit = 1;  k = 1;
        while (k < howmanynums)
        {
            a += x & bit ? sequence[k] : -sequence[k];
            k++;
            bit *= 2;
        }
        divisible = a % mod == 0;
        x--;
    }
    printf("%s", divisible ? "Divisible": "Not divisible");
    return 0;
}
```